# how get json data from wordpress api?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest

I created a REST API with wordpress to get some json data and this is the link is return all the data for me :
https://alternativeviager.fr/wp-json/get-all-alternativeviager/v1/go

and from another domain i have another website made with wordpress also i create PHP script to get those data :

```
function file_contents($path) {
    $str = @file_get_contents($path);
    if ($str === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot access '$path' to read contents.");
    } else {
        return $str;
    }
}

try {
    $json_data = file_contents("https://alternativeviager.fr/wp-json/get-all-alternativeviager/v1/go");
    var_dump($json_data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Deal with it.
    echo "Error: " , $e->getMessage();
}
```

and i got this error instead :

> Error: Cannot access
> 'https://alternativeviager.fr/wp-json/get-all-alternativeviager/v1/go'
> to read contents.

some help please

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your other website is also WordPress, you should consider using the [wp_remote_get()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/) function that WordPress provides.

---

However, to answer your question using `file_get_contents()`:

It seems your web server at `alternativeviager.fr` is blocking requests that do not contain the `User-Agent` header.

I've modified your `file_contents` function to include the User-Agent below. Feel free to choose a more suitable User-Agent.

```php
function file_contents($path)
{
    $opts = [
        'http' => [
            'header' => 'User-Agent: PHP'
        ]
    ];

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    
    $str = @file_get_contents($path, false, $context);

    if ($str === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot access '$path' to read contents.");
    }

    return $str;
}
```

I would also recommend you avoid using `@` to suppress errors as this is preventing the underlying 403 response from being reported which would have helped you to debug the original issue.